# Binding DataTable to jTable grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid, jquery-jtable

When I bind a list of structures to a jTable grid, it works. For example, my structure is like below:

```
class A {
    public string c1 = "test-c1";
    public string c2 = "test-c2";
}
```

In my controller if I return `List<A>` to jTable's load method as JSON, it works fine. The jTable is showing the grid.

The code for that is

```
return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = obj of List<A>, TotalRecordCount = studentCount });
```

Whereas if I have the same in a DataTable, like below

```
C1 C2
Test-c1 Test-C2
```

where C1 and C2 are data columns, and when I return the dt using above statement

```
return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = dt, TotalRecordCount = studentCount });
```

Theoretically, DataTable is also also a list of Rows. So why would this not work?

Comment: Check the generated json and see how the two results differ.

Comment: How do i check the generated JSON?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because jtable is expecting a Json containing the key-value pairs to bind the data.
If you look at the generated record property on javascript with a browser breakpoint, you'll see the problem.

Hope this helps somebody else.
Greetings,